# pre-commit and maven gitflow plugin

Tags: git, maven, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I'm happily using pre-commit to force myself using feature branches with a hook which checks if I'm committing in main/develop branch.

To support versioning etc etc I run `mvn gitflow:release` (see https://github.com/aleksandr-m/gitflow-maven-plugin) which does run `git commit`.

I wish to temporarily disable some hooks from pre-commit while the gitflow-maven-plugin is running; I know this could be done using the `SKIP=plugin-id` environment variable but this seems not to be passed to `git`.

How should I define the env in order to have it also during`git` execution ?